# Use two methods of controller for a single view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, view, controller

I don't know if it's obvious or that's what I do:

method get_counter in controller

```
def get_counter
  id = params[:id]

  login = id.split('@',2).first
  cust_split = id.split('@',2).last
  cust = cust_split.split('.',2).first

  if login
    id_address = ('ovm:b:'+cust+'/'+login)
  else
    id_address = ('ovm:b:'+cust)
  end

  raw_counter = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'c'))
  raw_counter_reset = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'overquota_reset_c'))
  raw_counter_reset_date = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'overquota_reset_at'))

  if raw_counter == nil
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:alert] = 'Error : wrong syntax or not present in the database'
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'index' }
    end
  else
    raw_counter_int = raw_counter.to_i

    bitwise_and_max = raw_counter_int & $mask_max
    decal_max = bitwise_and_max >> 53
    counter_max = 1024*(decal_max+1)
    @counter_max = counter_max

    counter_msg = raw_counter_int & $mask_msg
    @counter_msg = counter_msg

    if raw_counter_reset == '1'
      @counter_reset = 'oui'
    else
      @counter_reset = 'non'
    end
    @counter_reset_date = Time.at(raw_counter_reset_date.to_i)
  end
end
```

Now I try to separate this part :

```
  id = params[:id]

  login = id.split('@',2).first
  cust_split = id.split('@',2).last
  cust = cust_split.split('.',2).first

  if login
    id_address = ('ovm:b:'+cust+'/'+login)
  else
    id_address = ('ovm:b:'+cust)
  end

  raw_counter = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'c'))
  raw_counter_reset = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'overquota_reset_c'))
  raw_counter_reset_date = (REDIS.hget(id_address, 'overquota_reset_at'))

  raw_counter_int = raw_counter.to_i

  bitwise_and_max = raw_counter_int & $mask_max
  decal_max = bitwise_and_max >> 53
  counter_max = 1024*(decal_max+1)
  @counter_max = counter_max

  counter_msg = raw_counter_int & $mask_msg
  @counter_msg = counter_msg

  if raw_counter_reset == '1'
    @counter_reset = 'oui'
  else
    @counter_reset = 'non'
  end
  @counter_reset_date = Time.at(raw_counter_reset_date.to_i)
```

Who stay in method get_counter. And this part :

```
  if raw_counter == nil
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:alert] = 'Error : wrong syntax or not present in the database'
      format.html { redirect_to action: 'index' }
    end
  else
    get_counter
  end
```

That goes into the method show of controller.
Infact I try to separate the redirection in the show method because get_counter can also be used to edit the method.

Comment: "redirect_to action:" is something new to my eyes... I've known "render action:"... redirect_to works for urls... Pardon me if I'm outdated...

Comment: also you could try to define  _view_for_method_one.html.erb and _view_for_method_two.html.erb and render them in view_for_both.html.erb